# How to maintain state across android service instances

Tags: android, service

I'm working on an android app that will launch a background task, and eventually the user needs to be able to stop the background task.  My approach is:

- Launch activity
- Activity binds to service
- Activity starts service using an intent targeted at the service
- Service launches background task and returns START_STICKY from onStartCommand
- Later, user returns to activity
- Activity rebinds and restarts service
- Activity tells service to stop the background task using a method exposed from the returned IBinder

The reasoning behind using a service is that I originally thought the service would stay alive for the lifetime of the application, but I'm finding that the android platform must be killing my service and restarting it at a later time (confirmed by receiving a null intent in onStartCommand).  Not a big deal, though, as long as I still have a handle on the background task so I can kill it.  So my approach now is to store the reference to the background task in a static variable within the service class.  I'm not wild about this, but it seems like it should work.  The problem I'm facing is that when the service is reinstantiated my static variables have been reset, i.e. the reference to the task is null (as well as other static variables).  This is where I'm getting confused.  Is an android 'process' not the same as a traditional java process?  I can't see why it wouldn't be, and if it is then the static variables should maintain their state.  If it isn't, how is a new service instance supposed to stop a task that was previously started?

I'm not using any special 'process' attributes in my manifest, just the defaults.